# shiftKey Event Attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have two submit buttons: 'positive' and 'negative' in my html part. What i want to happen is that when user presses SHIFT KEY  and then does mousedown anywhere on the body the POSITIVE BUTTON should get submitted and the NEGATIVE BUTTON should get submitted on pressing CTRL KEY and doing mousedown. My code is as follows:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function check(event)
        {
        if (event.shiftKey==1)
        {
            var b1=document.getElementById('btn1');
            b1.submit();
        }

        if (event.ctrlKey==1)
        {
            var b1=document.getElementById('btn1');
            b2.submit();
        }

        }
 </script>
</head>
<body onmousedown="check(event)">
    <form method="post" action="fetch_page.php">
   <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Positive" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
   <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Negative" id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

Can someone tell me where am i going wrong??

Comment: In your second `if` you have `b2.submit()` after assigning `b1`. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="fetch_page.php">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Positive" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Negative" id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
    </form>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (e.shiftKey) document.getElementById('btn1').click();
            if (e.ctrlKey)  document.getElementById('btn2').click();
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
```